# Why is this error, 'Sequence contains no elements', happening?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am getting an Invalid Operation Exception, the stack is down below. I think it is because `db.Responses.Where(y => y.ResponseId.Equals(item.ResponseId)).First();` is not returning any results. I checked the response data and the userResponseDetails has a ResponseId, I also just used a hard coded value. I also know that the statement that calls this one is adding the Responses row that this function should be calling.  (This was working about a month ago and I don't remember changing anything that would break this)

```
[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable`1 source) +269
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.&lt;GetElementFunction&gt;b__0(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +41
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +59
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +133
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +87
   System.Linq.Queryable.First(IQueryable`1 source) +251
   InSight.Controllers.ForecasterController.userResponseDetails(List`1 userResponseDetails) +1039
```

Here is the offending code.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult userResponseDetails(List<ResponseDetailsPartial> userResponseDetails)
    {

        foreach (ResponseDetailsPartial item in userResponseDetails)
        {
            ResponseDetails temp = new ResponseDetails();
            temp.ResponseId = item.ResponseId;
            temp.ResponseDetailVal = item.ResponseDetailVal;
            temp.QuestioChoicesId = item.QuestioChoicesId;
            temp.Response = db.Responses
                  .Where(y => y.ResponseId.Equals(item.ResponseId)).First();
            temp.QuestionChoice = db.QuestionChoices
                   .Where(x => x.QuestionChoicesId.Equals(item.QuestioChoicesId)).First();
          db.ResponseDetails.Add(temp);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Json(new { ResponseDetailsId = userResponseDetails }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is the AJAX that calls this specific action:

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '/Forecaster/userResponseDetails/',
         data: JSON.stringify(rdetail),
         dataType: 'json',
         contentType: 'application/json',
     })
```

and this is rdetail after it has been strigified:

```
[{"ResponseId":118,"ResponseDetailVal":0.36,"QuestioChoicesId":null}]
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Check again. Use debugger if must. My guess is that for some item in userResponseDetails this query finds no elements:

```
.Where(y => y.ResponseId.Equals(item.ResponseId))
```

so you can't call

```
.First()
```

on it. Maybe try

```
.FirstOrDefault()
```

if it solves the issue.

Do NOT return NULL value! This is purely so that you can see and diagnose where problem is. Handle these cases properly.

Comment: This helped identify the real issue.  The value passed in wasn't being mapped right because of a typo in my model.

Comment: disagree. FIrstOrDefault will *remove* that error, not the issue. Returning a null may not be what the OP want. Check why you may end up with 0 records and act accordingly

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini totally agree. This is not a proper solution, but "as a test" meant to help with identification of the issue, and fining real solution is up to op

Comment: This is the right solution if you don't care about if it doesn't exist for example parsing an xml file where not always is there an element

Answer (score 8):

If this is the offending line:

```
db.Responses.Where(y => y.ResponseId.Equals(item.ResponseId)).First();
```

Then it's because there is no object in `Responses` for which the `ResponseId == item.ResponseId`, and you can't get the `First()` record if there are no matches.

Try this instead:

```
var response
  = db.Responses.Where(y => y.ResponseId.Equals(item.ResponseId)).FirstOrDefault();

if (response != null)
{
    // take some alternative action
}
else
    temp.Response = response;
```

The `FirstOrDefault()` extension returns an objects default value if no match is found. For most objects (other than primitive types), this is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line.

```
temp.Response = db.Responses.Where(y => y.ResponseId.Equals(item.ResponseId)).First();
```

You are calling First but the collection returned from db.Responses.Where is empty.