# "Sequence contains no matching element" Error. Is there some limits with SQL Server Express and EF in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am building a substantial ASP.Net MVC app using the latest EF and MVC.  Suddenly nothing works, every one of my index views now produces the following error when its generates the data to send to the index view:

> System.InvalidOperationException {"Sequence contains no matching element"}

This is happening in code that was generated when I added a controller with views. It now effects ALL my index views and there are about 40 of them which all worked previously and now none of them work. The only thing I can think of is that I hit some limit as I am just adding very similar controllers.

Comment: Possible solutions of your trouble?

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/21008130/5046188][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21008130/5046188

Comment: Error screen for a Contoller View that has worked for 3 months;
Sequence contains no matching element

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element

Source Error: 


Line 49:         ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
Line 50: 
Line 51:         var tags = from s in db.Tags.Include(s => s.TagGroup)
Line 52:                    select s;

Comment: Please post some code showing the issue. You are using First() somewhere were you should be using FirstOrDefault()

Comment: The error occurs the moment i try to access the database, in code that has accessed the database hundreds of times.  The error is Runtime, so I assume it has something to do with my runtime environment pertaining to SQL Express

Comment: Run your queries in SSMS and see what they return. Use SQL Server Profiler to inspect the queries being sent by the application to the server and see if anything's amiss. It sounds like you have a Linq term that expects a result (e.g. `First()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`) for a query which is not returning anything. Are you using a non-deterministic or date-based predicate?

Comment: Agree with the others here. If you use `First()`, `Last()`, etc., then you need to wrap it in a `try...catch` block to catch this exception and recover gracefully. Alternatively, use the `*OrDefault` variations, e.g. `FirstOrDefault()`, which won't raise exceptions. However, then, you need to do proper null-checking to ensure you don't run into `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exceptions elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Agree with all. And my opinion on try catch or using FirstOrDefault is that you should prefer FirstOrDefault. Don't use try catch if you have alternatives. Same goes for TryParse above try catch. It makes it easier to catch the interesting thrown errors when debugging without breaking on these. A null check isn't harder then a try catch.

Comment: If you can access the database from your debugger, set your code to stop on thrown CLR exceptions, so you can see immediately where it breaks and with which values.

Comment: I created a copy of my project and removed the Controller, the Model and the views which I created today.  I also modified the master model and removed the DBSETS and recompiled without any errors.  Yet when I go to the first Table / Model/ View / Controller that I set up 3 moths ago which has been working up to today I am still getting the error. So it must be something internal.  This project does not have a repository and it is virtually all EF generated code using the Code First approach.

Comment: For those who want to see the code, I can't paste it here so I set up the same problem on ASP.Net

https://forums.asp.net/t/2057091.aspx?Sequence+contains+no+matching+element

Comment: Using Try / Catch fives me exactly the same info as the error screen, How does this help, if I cannot get ANY data from the database?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of my problem.  None of my previous work on this machine will work anymore.  They haven't been changed and they were all working.  The problem is that anything I run in Visual Studio (VWD 2013 and VS Community 2015) will NOT talk to SQL Express.

I became suspicious and removed the connection string from the problem App and got exactly the same message.  I then thought I would try it with Apps that I know worked, but I ran them first before I made any changes and they (five different apps) all produced the same error.

Yet If I look at Server Explorer it still works and it is using the same Web.Config connection string, because when I remark it Server Explorer will not access the database.

As I said from the start this is some internal problem as all the code was generated by Visual Studio and then it all failed, and all my other working Apps fail as well.

I will now test it on a different machine.

Comment: How is this the cause of your problem?  You're just re-iterating the problem, with no cause, or no solution...  It's obviously talking to the database, or you would be getting a different error (a connection error).  Have you checked your database to see if it still contains the data you expect?

Comment: I had to do a lot of testing to get to the cause of the problem.  It appears that Visual Studio does not like some classes being pasted into directories.  As I said most of my project is just little modifications to the code generated by EF, namely classes and controllers.  I developed a proof of concept and then rebuilt from scratch with a different database structure.  Some of my controllers and models has a lot of Attributes so rather than redoing them I just replaced the files with a paste, I used the same namespace and model names.

Comment: With more testing I discovered that a Model Class if replaced with a paste will not allow you to make a controller, even though the Model class builds successfully.  If I paste the coded within the class section then it does allow you to create a controller.  The big problem is VS hiding what its doing and its pathetic error messages.  Testing showed that this error message can also be caused by deleting your database connection string in Web Config.  Unfortunately the only solution once this happens is to rebuild the App from scratch and only paste within files and not the files themselves.

Comment: This is ridiculous with these limitations to what you can write.  Having to break the comment up into three comments.

Comment: That's plain wrong.  I don't know what you mean by "a paste into a directory", but obviously you messed something up in the process.  Visual Studio can't tell the difference between a file file that was copied in and one that wasn't... It's simply impossible.  You clearly did something different in your pasted content.

Answer (score 0):

I manually rebuilt it all and the problem appeared again when I added the last few Models.  So that was not the solution.  I got assisatnce on the ASP.Net forum from Krunal who provided a solution that worked and fixed both versions which had the problem.

I was working with Code First from the database. Krunal thought I was using Database first with Designer and suggested I use the Model Browser to refresh my model.  You don't get a Model Browser if you used Code First so I added a Database First Design Model which created a EDMX file, I then right clicked on that and opened the Model Browser.

I then rebuilt it and it all worked.  I then went back to the original version added an EDMX opened the Model Browser and it all worked fine.  **As I said from the start it was not a code issue it was an Internal problem with Visual Studio and SQL Express.**  No code was changed.